# Referencing cells above and to the left in script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm trying to make a script for a custom function in google spreadsheet to work out the hours worked in a day `function hwtd()`. I've got it perfect in the cell `(((F8-E8)+(F9-E9))+(IF((F10<E10), (F10-E10+$Q$3), (F10-E10))))` with the host cell being F11 through its long winded to type out and copy/paste breaks my flow of work.

My problem is after searching I can't work out how to reference cells relative to the host cell i.e. `[cell 3 above] - [cell 3 above and 1 left] = hours in shift 1 of 3` (then repeated again for shift 2 & 3 before adding them all together).

The math I can do, it's just the referencing from the host cell. What is the best way to resolve this and are you able to explain it as well?

Comment: Why don't you share a doc with us and show us the expected outcome?

Comment: here is a link to the doc containing the data https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KnZ9UVyzNCJiDMh3izCxFNpq-ukRoP4Mxn4K42sw5oc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: From your question, it is not clear that your interested in a script. What have you tried yourself?

Comment: function hwtd() {
  // Function to calculate hours worked in the day...
  var outNum = 0;     // this will hold the answer...
  
  outNum =     [cell 3 above] - [cell 3 above and 1 left] = hours in shift 1 of 3   // this the part where i need to reference the cells but repeated for the whole 3 shifts...
  return outNum;  // return the answer to the cell which has the formula...
}

Comment: Do you still want a script or are you happy with the solution I provided?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra I would like a script solution, thanks

Answer (score 2):

What you basically need to do is the following:

> sum the difference between the shift endings minus shift beginnings

That will result in this formula:

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(Q4:Q6-P4:P6))
```

### Example

I've prepare an example file for you, containing to styles: **[Working Hours](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oJJmYU80dVwV65i9Scc1vpF7mAG8DwyaX0AXQzbaeBo/edit?usp=sharing)**. The formulae are easily copied/pasted to fill in the next worker.

### Style 1

[image]

### Style 2

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that, it makes the whole function easier than what i was doing. I was originally looking for how to reference a cell from the host cell when using a google script so when i use the custom function in a cell it can refer to the cells relevant to where it is in the sheet

Comment: @user337368 You're welcome. Please mark the answer, if you will (http://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: @user3373268 Are you familiar with Google Apps Script?

Comment: a slight bit but not too much